# AngularJS checkbox to toggle my filter on/off

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

Hi I am trying to get a filter to return instances that have a certain quantity but can't seem to get it to work. What I have in my HTML:

I would like my filter to apply when I hit this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" ng-model='filterSales' >
```

Heres what I have:

```
<div class='col-md-12' ng-repeat='sku in value | QuantityFilter'>
```

I was just able to learn how to create a custom filter but now I am having trouble figuring out how to toggle it.

Comment: If you want help, include what your `QuantityFilter` is, what `filterSales` is, and what `value` is.  There isn't enough information to go on here to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know how you can see whether the checkbox is set or not, you can add a parameter to your filter function as shown in the example at the bottom of the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

You would need to add `:filterSales` to your ng-repeat where you apply the filter.

```
<div class='col-md-12' ng-repeat='sku in value | quantityFilter:filterSales'>
```

In js you need to add another parameter, in this example "array" contains the array which is repeated (in your case "value") and toggleVar has the checkbox value.

```
"use strict";

app.filter("quantityFilter", function () {

    function quantityFilter(array, toggleVar) {
        if(!toggleVar){
            return array;
        }

        let result = [];

       // TODO: Build new array based on your criteria

        return result;
    }

    return quantityFilter;
});
```